# count1[g]++ in which index of count1 this g will get stored?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define NO_OF_CHARS 256

bool areAnagram(char* str1, char* str2) { 
    // Create 2 count arrays and initialize all values as 0 
    int count1[NO_OF_CHARS] = { 0 }; 
    int count2[NO_OF_CHARS] = { 0 }; 
    int i; 


    for (i = 0; str1[i] && str2[i]; i++) { 
        count1[str1[i]]++; 
        count2[str2[i]]++; 
    } 

    if (str1[i] || str2[i]) 
        return false; 

    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_CHARS; i++) 
        if (count1[i] != count2[i]) 
            return false; 

    return true; 
}

int main() { 
    char str1[] = "geeksforgeeks"; 
    char str2[] = "forgeeksgeeks"; 

    if (areAnagram(str1, str2)) 
        printf("The two strings are anagram of each other"); 
    else
        printf("The two strings are not anagram of each other"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

When `i = 0;` then `count1[str[i]]++` will contain `count1['g']++` and `count1` is an *array of 256 size each initialised with `0`*.

My question here is: In which index (from `0` to `256`) of  `count1`, `count1[`g`]` will get stored and after getting stored on that index what it will do next?

Comment: Your question seems like to follow the behavior of an [*XY Problem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i m asking here that this is a program of counting the frequency of each char given in str..so i m asking when i=0 str[0]=g and count1[str[i]] will become equal to count1[g] and g is going to store in count1 which is an array of 256 int blocks . so in which index of count1 g will get stored and how g will store bcz g is an char and index is int

Answer (score 1):

using ASCII code for each char:
g - 103 - 01100111
so `count1['g']` = `count1[103]`

after that, every `char` have its count on `count1` for string1 and `count2` for string2, then the next code compares its count and returns true if the count is the same.

Comment: check ASCII table here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: could u please elaborate ur answer..i would be thankful to u

Comment: so char g will get stored in the index no. 103 of count1?????but what if the size of count1 is less than 50 in this case where g will store???

Comment: ASCII has 256 char, so if you use this method make sure the array minimum size is 256. If you need to use less size of the array, you can define manually each char that possible be your input

Comment: could you please tell me how can i define each char manually ????bro m new in programming it would be a great help

Comment: let's say a=1 and z=26, so you need to define like if(char=='a')count1[1]++; if(char=='b')count1[2]++; until 'z'. Example of your question more simple than this method, but I hope this will give you another way to do so